# How to use Eltima eveusbc to share / connect a usb device encrypted?

Tags: usb, encryption, remote-connection

I'm able to view shared usb devices using `eveusbc ls shared`:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 00X Device 00X: ID <some hex>:<some num> IBM Corp.
...

$ eveusbc ls shared
acquired ,,1810,usbX,X-X,,4XXX SXXXMXXX Printer,,E,,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,
```

I'm also able to view

```
$ eveusbc ls remote
connected SOME_HOST,,SOME_PORT,usbX,portX,,,,E,,,
```

But I'm unsure of how to share / connect the devices when encryption is used...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from Eltima's wiki covering how to share a device with encryption enabled:

> share tcp_port devname [nickname encrypt password] or share – share local USB port on given tcp_port. ‘encrypt’ can be number (set if non-zero) or y, yes, true, encrypt.

Source: https://www.eltima.com/wiki/user-guides/usb-to-ethernet/command-line-linux.html

I suppose for connecting the device a specific command is not required.

Comment: I saw that. It didn't really clear things up; I wonder if there's more documentation that explains `devname`, `[nickname encrypt password]` since when I share it using the UI, it doesn't ask for anything like that.

Comment: What is the `devname`?  Where does that come from?